# Bad html output

Tags: php

Trying to write form of registration.

```
<?php 
    include_once 'core.php';

    if (User::IsAuthorization()) {
        header("Location: /");
    }

    if(!is_null($_POST["Registration"])){
        User::Registration($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]);
        $user = new User();
        $user->Authorization($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]);
        $user->SetSession();
        header("Location: /");
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="registration.html" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="login">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Регистрация" name="Registration">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This form works correctly on my friend's laptop. But in my case, the output contains come code of php. I use denwer as local server.
it contains this code(but it doesn't have to):

```
Authorization($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]); $user->SetSession(); header("Location: /"); } ?>
```

Link to picture: http://s23.postimg.org/5vv204qor/Capture.png

Comment: then your friend is running a server and php, and you are not.

Comment: I am running server too

Comment: is the file called via "localhost/file.php" in the browser not the raw local file path

Comment: Does the file name end with .html? If so, change to .php

Answer (score 0):

Simply start your server and use localhost to show it on webpage.
It should shows the same page as the one being shown on your fd's laptop.

If it does not, it probably forgot to include  or change html to php in the file name.

Thanks